# Manipular elementos HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se com apenas javascript eu consigo manipular os elementos de uma **HTMLCollection** da mesma forma que eu faria com usando o seletor do jQuery.

Por exemplo pegar o resultado de `document.getElementsByClassName('ativo')` e adicionar a todos os elementos encontrados a classe '*maior*'.

Comment: Sim, porque jQuery é javascript (biblioteca Javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturalmente que sim, basta você iterar sobre o resultado e adicionar a classe desejada. Veja um exemplo simples em que itero o resultado com o `for`:

```js
const itens = document.getElementsByClassName('ativo');

for (let item of itens) {
  item.classList.add("maior");
}
```

```css
.maior {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ativo">Texto 1</div>
<div class="ativo">Texto 2</div>
<div class="ativo">Texto 3</div>
<div class="ativo">Texto 4</div>
```